# Django views.register returning none instead of a HTTPresponse

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make a custom user registration form

Here is my views.py code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .forms import RegistrationForm
# Create your views here.

def register(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("profile/")

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', context)
```

Here is my forms.py code

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
    model = User
         fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

When I run this code it's working but when I try to register a user it is returning

```
ValueError at /accounts/registration/
The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It 
returned None instead.
```

Here accounts is the name of my Django app

Comment: `return redirect("profile/")` change to `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("profile"))`

Comment: The comment isn't gonna fix it. It's not about the `HttpResponse` that you return, it's about the one you _don't_ return... :)

Comment: request.method == 'POST' will be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `views.py`, you're only returning `redirect()` if the request is of type `POST` *and* the form is valid; or if you receive any other request type. You're not handling the case in which the request type is `POST` and the form is invalid. This can be easily fixed by extending the statement:

```
def register(request):

    # Always use request.method to check whether it's a POST or GET request 
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html', context)

    form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

    if not form.is_valid():
        # Handle the case in which the form is invalid here.
        # Make sure you return redirect() or render() here.

    # Now we're in the case in which the form _is_ valid
    form.save()
    return redirect("profile/")
```

I have also made your code a little more pythonic and reduced the complexity of the if-statements. Please note to always use `request.method` to validate the type of the incoming request. In any case, your view should always return a `redirect()` or `render()` object to avoid the error quoted in your question.

Comment: Now I get in. I'm not returning anything if the form is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Move the last two lines of your view back one indent level, so that they execute in all cases.