# Why does Django custom User Registration Form returns None instead of HttpResponse and no Form errors are showing?

Tags: django-forms, django-templates

I'm learning Django and trying to build a user registration page with a simple custom user form with just a few more fields then the default `UserCreationForm`. When I submit the registration form, I get a Django debug error message saying:

```
The view catalog.views.librarian_add_user didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I'm using python 3.8.15 with Django 4.1.4.

I've created a `UserRegistrationForm` in `forms.py`:

```python
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User  # I import from .models and not from django.contrib.auth.models for consistency's sake

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=101, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=101, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        )
```

A function view `librarian_add_user` in `views.py`:

```python
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm

def librarian_add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("User added successfully."))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:index'))
        # else:
        #     print(form.errors)  # I can see the errors printed in my terminal, which means `form.is_valid()` failed
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        context = {
            'user_form': form,
        }
        return render(
            request,
            'catalog/librarian_add_user.html',
            context,
        )
```

and the `librarian_add_user.html` in my templates:

```html
{% extends 'catalog/base_generic.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if perms.catalog.can_mark_returned %}

    {% if user_form.errors %}
        {{ user_form.errors }}
    {% endif %}

    <h1>Add a new user</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ user_form.as_p }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>

{% endif %}
```

I will omit the path in `urls.py` for simplicity.

As commented inline in `views.py`, I've tried adding a nested `else` clause in `librarian_add_user` function view and can see the `form.errors` printed in my terminal in an HTML unordered list. I have hypothesized maybe this is due to `UserRegistrationForm` in `forms.py` did not validate whether `password1` equaled `password2`. I was able to rule that out by deliberately typing different passwords between `password1` and `password2`, and getting the appropriate form error message in my terminal.

I have also tried using the same nested `else` clause to create an "else" scenario where a unbounded form is shown along with an error message. Like this:

```python
def librarian_add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:index'))
        else:
            form = UserRegistrationForm()  # <--- HERE!
            context = {
                'user_form': form
            }
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        ...
        return render(
            request,
            'catalog/librarian_add_user.html',
            context,
        )
```

I know this is redundant but still the `user_form.errors` don't show up in the newly rendered unbounded form.

I have also tried putting the form validation work in the `forms.py` file according to the Stackoverflow suggested post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951133/django-views-register-returning-none-instead-of-a-httpresponse), with the following changes to `forms.py`:

```python
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=101, required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=101, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            ...   # same as above and omitted for simplicity
        )
    
    def save(self, commit=True):   # <--- ENTIRE METHOD HERE
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        
        if commit:
            user.save()
        
        return user
```

And these changes to `views.py`:

```python
def librarian_add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()   # <--- HERE
            login(request, user)    # <--- HERE    
            messages.success(request, ("User added successfully."))   # <--- HERE
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:index'))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        ...
        return render(
            request,
            'catalog/librarian_add_user.html',
            context,
        )
```

This is probably some thing simple and really stupid but I have spend last afternoon, evening, and whole day today looking at it with no avail. Could someone help take a look and help answer the following questions?

1. Do I need a nested `else` clause for the case when `form.is_valid()` fails? Even the tutorial on MDN and Django doesn't do this.
2. Why is it that my `form.errors` does not show in the template and how is this related (which I think it is) to `form.is_valid()` failing and returning `None`?
3. How can I fix my code so I can register a new test user?

Thanks so much for helping a new comer!

**SOLUTION:**

I was able to solve the issue thanks to the suggestion from @srn, through the final result is a little different.

There are two ways to solve this. One way is to build a nested else clause that deals with the case when `form.is_valid()` is false. It keeps the data already entered (but not yet bounded to the form object) and just renders the form with the data.*

*For those who are confused about this, I learned from this error that althought I have filled out the form and pressed the "register" button, data binding to the form object DOES NOT HAPPEN until `form.is_valid()`.

The `views.py` function view looks like this:

```python
def librarian_add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("User added successfully."))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:librarian-manage-member', kwargs={'username': user.username}))
        else:   # <--- HERE!
            return render(request, 'catalog/librarian_add_user.html', {'user_form': form})
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

        context = {
            'user_form': form,
        }
        return render(
            request,
            'catalog/librarian_add_user.html',
            context,
        )
```

The second way is more elegant IMO and is where my code deviated from all the examples in the official Django documentation. All I needed to do is to fix an indentation error after the outer `else` clause so that the `context` variable and `return` command covers the scenario where `form.is_valid()` is false. This fixed all my issues as shown below:

```python
def librarian_add_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            messages.success(request, ("User added successfully."))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('catalog:librarian-manage-member', kwargs={'username': user.username}))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()

    context = {   # <--- Outdented from here to the end
        'user_form': form,
    }
    return render(
        request,
        'catalog/librarian_add_user.html',
        context,
    )
```

As shown above, the outer `if/else` clause now only deals with whether the request is POST or GET, and the inner `if` clause only returns and exits the program if `form.is_valid()` is true. I can't believe I was on this for two days...(facepalm)

So to answer my own questions:

1. Yes, there needs to be coverage for the scenario where `form.is_valid()` is false. It could be explicit with an `else` clause, or outdenting the code following the `if/else` conditions to catch that scenario.
2. Since `form.is_valid()` case was not covered, there was no page rendered and hence no error information.
3. See the two approaches above.

At the end, this goes to show after three years of programming and building apps (non-production) as a hobby, I can still make simple mistakes. So don't ever get discouraged, stupid mistakes will happen years down the road...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something returns None, it usually means that nothing was returned.

In your case this can happen in librarian_add_user().

if form.is_valid() is not True, the function will return nothing at all, None.

This happens because you only provide what it shall do in case it is True. If it isn't, the code won't magically jump back to the "outer" if/else clause.

Example:

```
def foo(baz):
    if baz == 1:
        return(1)

>>> x = foo(2)
>>> type(x)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

So yes, you should try to return something if the form is not valid, for readability from within an else-condition on the same level as the matching 'if'.

Comment: Thanks @srn. I was able to solve the issue thanks to your suggestion. I have also updated my original post with the changes I have made. I hope more people learning and avoid my mistake.